# getting code completion support for diadem scripting

Tags: python, scripting, language-server-protocol, pyright

I'm working with the scripting engine in DIAdem at the moment. I would like to use an external editor to edit code since the internal editor is quite limited.

For context, every DIAdem script starts with:

```py
from DIAdem import Application as dd
```

Then all scripting functions are available from the `dd` object.

Using VSCode with pyRight, I have had limited success by adding the following `pyrightconfig.json` to my script root:

```json
{
    "executionEnvironments": [
        {
            "root": "C:\\Program Files\\National Instruments\\DIAdem 2023",
            "extraPaths": [
                "C:\\Program Files\\National Instruments\\DIAdem 2023"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Now pyRight will recognize `DIAdem.Application` since the `DIAdem.py` file is now in the (supposed) execution root. However, I'm still missing all the member functions, which is unsurprising since `Application` is defined in `DIAdem.py` as follows:

```py
vp=ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_void_p)
GPI=ctypes.WinDLL("GfSGPI.dll")  
vp=GPI.TOCMDGet()
obj=pythoncom.ObjectFromAddress(vp,'{00020400-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}')
Application=win32com.client.dynamic.Dispatch(obj)
```

The internal editor in DIAdem does have completion for builtin DIAdem functions, but I can't find a type stub file or something similar so I'm not sure where it's getting them from.

Understanding exactly what's going on here is a bit above my skill level, so I'd happily welcome any suggestions you might have.